# Time with minutes and Hours wheel type in android

Tags: android

I am developing wheel type piker in android which should show Min figure with Min text and hour figure with hour text but it is displaying same text Min or hour what should I do to separate Min and hour.
    I got code from following link.

```
android-wheel Android Picker widget
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel-demo/src/kankan/wheel/demo/CitiesActivity.java

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/downloads/list*
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) and [this one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker).
They both supply sample codes.